# How to submit a change or request clarification to ISO technical committee

Tags: c, prototype, specifications

I submitted a question on *['prototype scope'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736560/c-prototype-scope)* and wanted to know the reason for its origination.

After some serious deliberations (please see the answers there) I think a clarification regarding the existence of the 'prototype scope' is needed.

I am thinking of how it has to be done? What is the process for submitting a request (for clarification) to the ISO technical committee? Please throw some light on it.

Comment: What exactly is the clarification you'd propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to do it informally, but still want to contact some of the people involved in writing the C standards, you may wish to try the [comp.lang.c.moderated](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c.moderated/topics) or [comp.std.c](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/topics) newsgroups. I have generally found these to include people who really know what they are talking about.